# How to achieve programatic routing in Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

`Nuxt` comes with pre-configured router out of the box and we can use `<NuxtLink to="/about" prefetch>About page</NuxtLink>`. However, how to achieve programmatic routing?

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to have a simple and straightforward answer. But sometimes, we end up surfing the web for a long time and landing up on not what we are looking for a lot of time.

Answer to this question is simple. You can do it in a same way as you do it in normal vue.js app using `this.$router.push`.

```
this.$router.push({ path: val });
```